# How to select 1 row for a person that has 2 accounts in the system

Tags: sql, db2, toad

**1st part to achieve:** I'm trying to return the row for a person "ABC1" where it has the APP_START_DT.
or APP_SUBMIT_DT but I want to return the Acct_CR_DT as well which in this case is 9/5/2018 and I don't want duplicates. One row per person for records like these.

**2 part I want to achieve:** When they have any date, return the latest status based on that, which is this case it should look at the "APP_SUBMIT_DT" and return "App submitted"

```
My Table:
ID     NAME    Acct_CR_DT    App_Ap    APP_START_DT    APP_SUBMIT_DT
44444  ABC1    9/5/2018      My univ   9/5/2018        9/14/2018
44444  ABC1    10/2/2018     {null}    {null}          {null}




Desired Results:   
ID     NAME   Acct_CR_DT  App_Ap   APP_START_DT  APP_SUBMIT_DT App_stat
44444  ABC1   9/5/2018    My univ  9/5/2018      9/14/2018     Submt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id, name, min(acct_cr_dt) as acct_cr_dt, min(app_ap) as app_at,
       min(app_start_dt) as app_start_dt), min(app_submit_dt) as app_submit_dt
from t
group by id, name;
```

Answer (score 0):

another option you can use window function row_number()

```
 select *  from 
 (
  select t.*,row_number()over(partition by id, name order by Acct_CR_DT) rn
  from table_name t
 ) t1 where t1.rn=1
```

Comment: thanks, but that'll eliminate other people with the data that only has Acct Cr DT. I want to capture them as well.

Comment: Just remove null checking

Comment: I tried your query and it didn't work. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by removing NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you need the oldest acct_crt_dt and app_start_dt and the newer app_submit_dt.  Also, if for some reason you need the list of app_ap in a single string, use listagg (supported on Oracle and Db2, I don't know if it is supported on other RDBMSs):

```
select id, name, min(acct_cr_dt) as acct_cr_dt, listagg(app_ap,', ') as app_at,
   min(app_start_dt) as app_start_dt, max(app_submit_dt) as app_submit_dt
from t
group by id, name
```

But be careful with two possible situations: same ID with different NAME and same NAME with different ID.